# Cell not updating value as UISlider value changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I have a question that is driving me crazy. It is all about updating, in real time, an UITableViewCell with the value of an UISlider that is inside another UITableViewCell.

### The problem

The cell is updated but It seems that the size of the Label in the cell does not addapt to the size of the value represented. I will try to explain better.

The UISlider has a minimumValue of -100 and a maximum value of 100. So, the first time the TableView is loaded, the **cell.detailText.text** shows 0.0% witch is displayed ok, but when I move the slider and the value is bigger, for example 55.5%, the label can not hold this extra characters and it displays "55....."

#### This is how I create the cell that holds de UISlider Value create the UISlider in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

---

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:ProductCellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.textLabel.text=@"Performance";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", slider.value];
cell.tag=1002;
```

#### This is how I create de UISlider, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

---

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero                                                           reuseIdentifier:ProductCellIdentifier] autorelease];

slider = [[UISlideralloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 200, 25)];

slider.maximumValue = 100;
slider.minimumValue = -100;
slider.continuous = TRUE;

[slideraddTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
cell.tag=0;
[slider release];
```

#### And this is what I do in the sliderChanged method in order to update the cell.

---

```
UITableViewCell *celda= (UITableViewCell *)[[self tableView] viewWithTag:1002];
celda.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", slider.value];
```

I suspect that the solution is about the use of the *reloadData* method of the UITableView but not sure. I have tried inserting a `self.tableView.reloadData` in the sliderChanged method but I got then the UISlider does not move and finally I got this exception:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'*

Thanks in advance for your help
Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that detailTextLabel width is fixed and computed only when the label is going to be drawn in the cell.
so, when you initialize the label with "0.0%" there is room for exactly 4 characters, and you cannot visualize correctly anything with more than that; extra charactes are either trimmed with "..." or the label just doesn't display anything.

i worked around this issue by forcing the label to contain additional spaces at the beginning of the string like this:

```
while ([string length] <= 4)
      string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",prestring];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = string;
```

in this way, my slider can visualize correctly numbers from 0 to 999 correctly; since you have more characters just adjust the length desired.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `currencyStyleStringFromNumber:` when you update the cell's value? I would think you'd get better results using the same kind of initializer you do when you first put the slider's value into the cell, that is:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", slider.value];
```

Comment: Tim, this is exactly as I have the code. I typed it incorrectly. I have updated the description of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you access the cell (by tag) might not get you the cell you expect. Didn't you originally assign the tag 1002? Check the value of `celda`. And then, just to check, set the value of the cell's label to something less obscure.

Comment: Sorry Nikolai, as Tim noted, I have pasted the code of other class. As you can see in the corrected version, I am accesing the cell with tag 1002. So it is supposed that this is the correct way to access the cell.